# Unable to start activity in preference fragment when I included preference headers

Tags: android

I have problem with PreferenceFregment. Am I missing something ? Before I had only preference files worked fine. Then I include headers. Seems like I miss something somewhere.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          Process: com.example.tallycounter.tallycounter, PID: 25931
>                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tallycounter.tallycounter/com.example.tallycounter.tallycounter.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Subclasses of PreferenceActivity must override isValidFragment(String) to verify that the Fragment class is valid! com.example.tallycounter.tallycounter.SettingsActivity has not checked if fragment com.example.tallycounter.tallycounter.SettingsActivity$SettingsFragment is valid.
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Subclasses of PreferenceActivity must override isValidFragment(String) to verify that the Fragment class is valid! com.example.tallycounter.tallycounter.SettingsActivity has not checked if fragment com.example.tallycounter.tallycounter.SettingsActivity$SettingsFragment is valid.
>                                                                                              at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.isValidFragment(PreferenceActivity.java:940)
>                                                                                              at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeaderInner(PreferenceActivity.java:1222)
>                                                                                              at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeader(PreferenceActivity.java:1249)
>                                                                                              at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:586)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>   02-01 09:31:49.509 1506-1991/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.tallycounter.tallycounter/.SettingsActivity
>   02-01 09:31:49.514 1506-1991/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.tallycounter.tallycounter/.SettingsActivity

My class :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

import java.util.List;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    /*@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }*/
    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

            String settings = getArguments().getString("settings");
            if ("pref".equals(settings)) {
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xml preferenceHeaders

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header
        android:fragment="com.example.xxx.xxx.SettingsActivity$SettingsFragment"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="General">
        <extra
            android:name="settings"
            android:value="pref">
        </extra>
    </header>
</preference-headers>
```

Comment: I tried to add   "@Override
    protected boolean isValidFragment (String fragmentName) {
        return SettingsFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    } but still doesn't work. Have I missed anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey Well I find where the problem was. Gona post it in case anyone else will have same problem. I maked preference fragment subclass to preference activity. And isValidFregment didn't work. Hope it will help to someone!

My preference fragment class (SettingsFragment.class) :

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String settings = getArguments().getString("settings");
        if ("xxx".equals(settings)) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_xxx);
        } else if ("yyy".equals(settings)) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_yyy);
        }
    }
}
```

My preference activity class (SettingsActivity.class) :

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return SettingsFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }
}
```

And my XML preference headers :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header
        android:fragment="com.example.xxx.xxx.SettingsFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pref_milestone"
        android:title="Xxx">
        <extra
            android:name="settings"
            android:value="xxx">
        </extra>
    </header>
    <header
        android:fragment="com.example.xxx.xxx.SettingsFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pref"
        android:title="Yyy">
        <extra
            android:name="settings"
            android:value="yyy">
        </extra>
    </header>
</preference-headers>
```